# Setting a different background image in a subclass in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone

We are using a base class where we set the background picture.  That code looks like:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"App_Background.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
int offset = 0;

imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, bounds.size.height - image.size.height + offset, image.size.width, image.size.height); 
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin; 
imageView.tag = BACKGROUND_TAG;
[self.view insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0]; // insert it behind all other views in NIB

self.background = [imageView autorelease]; // cleanup
```

If I want to use this as my superclass for another UIViewController but do not want to use the backgound, how do I do that?  I thought I could do this in my subclass' viewDidLoad:

```
UIView *theBackgroundView = [self.view viewWithTag:BACKGROUND_TAG ];
theBackgroundView = nil;
```

But that doesn't work.  Any thoughts?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call `[super viewDidLoad]` *first*. Then do `[[self.view viewWithTag: BACKGROUND_TAG] removeFromSuperview]`.